# setSelected method isn't working for a jCheckBox

Tags: java, user-interface

I have this snippet of code here:

```
            String priorityCheck = model.getValueAt(row, 5).toString();
        if (priorityCheck.equals("Priority"))
        {
            Priority_Checkbox.setSelected(true);
        }
```

and I am basically trying to get the values of whatever the row has into textfields/checkboxes underneath the table when it is clicked on. However, I have an error with the 'setSelected' method, is something else required for a jCheckbox?

Comment: *" I have an error with the 'setSelected' method"* - Do you have a compiler error or a runtime error or does it just not work?

Comment: The error just says 'cannot find symbol' within netbeans, and it's a compiler error

Comment: Sooo, you have a compiler error - which seems like `Priority_Checkbox` isn't defined within the context of where you're trying to use it - a [mcve] would go along way to helping understand the context of the issue

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm having a hard time trying to find the exact context of this in my code, as the only thing I am referencing is the jCheckbox that is already part of my GUI, if you'd like, I can give the entire method of the Event for the mouseclick, but I am not sure if it would provide much context outside of the error